# How Can I Autoload Items into my ListView with Custom Adapter

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, cwac-endless

I have a custom adapter for listView and I want to load my item parcial like first time this Activity started load firts 10 row or something like that I look up endless adapter but I couldn't find good example of endless adapter with custom adapter if you guys help me I will  be appreciated.

here is my custom adapter

```
public class DynamicListView extends BaseAdapter {

ImageLoader imageLoader;
Context c;
ArrayList<String> images = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> baslik = new ArrayList<String>() ;
ArrayList<String> icerik = new ArrayList<String>() ;
ArrayList<ListViews> lists = new ArrayList<ListViews>();
ArrayList<ArrayList> list1 = new ArrayList<ArrayList>();
ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList<String>();


DynamicListView(Context c ,ArrayList<ArrayList> list ,String tur)
{
    this.list1 = list;
    if(tur.equals("News"))
    {
        Log.i("For disi loglar",String.valueOf(list1.size()));
        for(int i = 0; i < list1.size() ; i++)
        {
            temp = list1.get(i);
            Log.i("Inside of For",list1.get(i).get(3).toString());
          images.add( temp.get(3) );
            Log.i("Inside of For",list1.get(i).get(0).toString());
          baslik.add( temp.get(0) );
            Log.i("Inside of For",list1.get(i).get(1).toString());
          icerik.add(temp.get(1));

        }
        temp.clear();
    }
    else if(tur.equals("Announcements"))
    {

    }


    this.c = c;
  imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();

    for(int i= 0 ; i < images.size() ; i++)
    {
        lists.add( new ListViews( images.get(i), baslik.get(i), icerik.get(i) ) );
    }
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return lists.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return lists.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    myViewHolder holder = null;
    if(row==null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflate = (LayoutInflater) c.getSystemService(c.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);//Butun layout u inflate'in icine aldik
        row = inflate.inflate(R.layout.dynamic_lists , parent , false ); //gerekli islemler
        holder = new myViewHolder(row);
        row.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (myViewHolder) row.getTag();
    }

    imageLoader.displayImage(lists.get(position).image,holder.image );
    holder.baslik.setText(lists.get(position).baslik);
    holder.icerik.setText(lists.get(position).icerik);

    return row;
}



class myViewHolder
{
    private ImageView image;
    private TextView baslik;
    private TextView icerik;
    myViewHolder(View v)
    {
        this.image = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.ivDynamic);
        this.baslik = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvDynamic1);
        this.icerik = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvDynamic2);
    }
}


class ListViews
{
    ListViews(String image, String baslik, String icerik)
    {
        this.baslik = baslik;
        this.icerik = icerik;
        this.image = image;
    }
    String image;
    String baslik;
    String icerik;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved when the list is scrolled to auto populate the next batch of data. Please see the below links:

1. [first](http://mobile.dzone.com/news/android-tutorial-dynamicaly)
2. [second](http://benjii.me/2010/08/endless-scrolling-listview-in-android/)

Lemme know if you are looking for something more custom.

Comment: In the second link where should I implements this code i found that page but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Create a separate class 'EndlessScrollListener' which in turn implements an Asynctask to load data dynamically. After you are done with the class add the onScrollListener to your list yourList.setOnScrollListener(new EndlessScrollListener());

Comment: See this example [here.] (http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/07/android-listview-load-more-data.html)

Comment: Your most welcome. Glad to help you out. I got one more working example. Just copy paste and you could see the effect. http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2066699&seqNum=4

Comment: If it's ok i just wanna ask one more question the last link you gave I look it up and implement it on my app but that is not an Acvivity how can I start it.

Comment: It's simple :). Make the MainActivity extend ListActivity (do remember to have a ListView with id = @android:id/list in your activity_main xml which is usually set in onCreate). Copy code from onActivityCreated into your onCreate method and replace occurrences of context with **this**. Rest everything will be same. Do the necessary imports and it should work. Tell me if it still doesn't and after you are done I can also tell you how to implement this using Fragments but first try out yourself. Happy coding.

Comment: Just to add if you want to run the current code as it is you will have to have another class extending Activity or FragmentActivity and add your MainActivity to it using FragmentManager and FragmentTransaction.